# How to make Chart JS responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, chart.js

I am using Chart.js with Twitter Bootstrap template. The Charts are not sized correctly if I don't mention a height and width for Canvas. But if I specify width and height then the charts are not responsive. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Just added a codepen to the answer btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chart.js has a property (responsive) that you can configure at the global or chart level via options that will make the chart responsive. See http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration > responsive

```
// Boolean - whether or not the chart should be responsive and resize when the browser does.
responsive: true,
```

true makes it responsive. false (default) makes it non-responsive.

---

Example usage (only the relevant part, check out the CodePen for the full exam)

```
var ctx = $("#bar").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barData, {
  responsive: true
});
```

CodePen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdrGVx

You might also want to check out the maintainAspectRatio option, if you want to maintain the ratio of width to height.

Comment: I think the [default is responsive (true)](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration)

Comment: For me it doesn't work. The Charts aren't readable. The resize really really down, so no bars are visible