# How to change width of the chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I have made a chart using Chart Js. However, as shown below, the chart does not fit inside the width. The attributes of `canvas` also does not really work. It seems that `height` works, but I can not modify the `width`(even if I change the value, it would not have that value). I have set `maintainAspectRatio` as false, and `reponsive` as true, but it would not help.

How do I make the chart fit inside the set width and height?

Any sugggestion or advice would be appreciated.

```
<canvas id="monthly-sales" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var monthlySales = document.getElementById("monthly-sales").getContext('2d');
        var monthlySalesChart = new Chart(monthlySales, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: listOfMonths.slice(10,2),
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Sales',
                    data: [
                        monthlyFees['sales'][10],
                        monthlyFees['sales'][11]
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Sales'
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true,
                            userCallback: function userCallback(tick) {
                                return (tick / 100000000);
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function label(tooltipItem, data) {
                            return numeral(tooltipItem.yLabel).format('0,0');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Html

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">This month</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card-chart">
                        <canvas id="monthly-sales" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Sales Changed: <span id="monthly-sales-changes"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card-chart">
                        <canvas id="monthly-profits" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card-chart">
                        <canvas id="monthly-orders" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried inline css in canvas?

Comment: @chiragsolanki Yes, I tried but it did not work.

Comment: can you show me the code somewhere like in fiddle?

Comment: @chiragsolanki  am not familiar with fiddle, so I have added some more codes

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html, and an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821223/how-to-make-chart-js-responsive

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Because `labels` were not correctly defined, the chart was not correctly drawn.